# Why is matrix multiplication with grayscale image matrix giving wrong output?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix-multiplication, grayscale

I loaded an image using `cv2.imread()` on Colab, and converted it into some grayscale image. I have a matrix `B`, which I have extracted from the same grayscale image. But when I am trying to multiply it by itself, that is, when I am evaluating `B@B`, then the output is coming out to be a matrix, but its entries are not same as we will get when we multiply `BxB`:

```
print("Required matrix is:\n", b)
print("BxB is:\n", b*b)
```

How will I get `BxB`?

Answer (score 3):

For NumPy arrays, the [`*`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) operator performs element-wise multiplication:

```
result[0, 0] = b[0, 0] * b[0, 0]
```

In your case, you most likely have `dtype=np.uint8`, such that you encounter integer overflows, for example:

```
result[0, 0] = b[0, 0] * b[0, 0] = 234 * 234 = 54576
```

Since `np.uint8` is limited to the value range `[0, ..., 255]`, you'd need to get `54576 % 256 = 228`, which is your `result[0, 0]`.

So, if you actually want to have element-wise multiplication without integer overflows, convert `b` to `np.int`, for example.

Or, if you actually want to have real matrix multiplication, also convert `b` to `np.int`, but also use the proper [`@`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) operator.

Here's some code for the different use cases:

```py
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[234, 229], [129, 11]], np.uint8)

print('Matrix b:\n', b, '\n')
# Matrix b:
#  [[234 229]
#  [129  11]] 

print('Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.uint8):\n',
      b * b, '\n')
# Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.uint8):
#  [[228 217]
#  [  1 121]] 

print('Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.int):\n',
      np.int_(b) * np.int_(b), '\n')
# Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.int):
#  [[54756 52441]
#  [16641   121]] 

print('Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.int) % 256:\n',
      (np.int_(b) * np.int_(b)) % 256, '\n')
# Element-wise multiplication b * b (np.int) % 256:
#  [[228 217]
#  [  1 121]] 

print('Actual matrix multiplication b @ b (np.int):\n',
      (np.int_(b) @ np.int_(b)), '\n')
# Actual matrix multiplication b @ b (np.int):
#  [[84297 56105]
#  [31605 29662]]
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
----------------------------------------
```